# RabbitMq Rpc: EventingBasicConsumer or QueueingBasicConsumer

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

The [tutorials on RabbitMq's site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) are pretty straight forward, but I noticed that in [the Rpc example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html), the developers choose to use the thread-blocking call `consumer.Queue.Dequeue()` instead of using the `EventingBasicConsumer` and the event handling model used elsewhere.

Looking through the [current documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) it is stated that

> As of version 3.5.0 application callback handlers can invoke blocking operations (such as `IModel.QueueDeclare` or `IModel.BasicCancel`). `IBasicConsumer` callbacks are invoked concurrently.

Where as [the old documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v1.5.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-1.5.0-user-guide.pdf) (v. 1.5.0) states that it is not supported

> Application callback handlers must not invoke blocking AMQP operations (such as
>   `IModel.QueueDeclare` or `IModel.BasicCancel`). If they do, the channel will deadlock. [...] For this reason, `QueueingBasicConsumer` is the safest way of subscribing to a queue.

Could it be that the RPC example hasn't been updated? Or am I missing something? I would very much appreciate to be pointed to some documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there is no need to use `QueueingBasicConsumer`.
There is [an issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/issues/58) in RabbitMQ tutorials repo about this.

I've sent [a pull request](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/pull/85) and it was merged, hope the documentation will be updated soon.